# is there a way to check if an animatorcontroller has a parameter?

Tags: unity, mecanim

With mecanim, if you try to set a parameter that doesn't exist, it logs a warning. It doesn't throw an exception or return null or anything useful like that.  So if I set a parameter very often that doesn't exist, a lot of CPU time is spent logging warnings. How can I tell if a parameter exists in an animatorcontroller?  It would be great if there was a method like [ProceduralMaterial.HasProceduralProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ProceduralMaterial.HasProceduralProperty.html) (which allows you to check if the ProceduralMaterial has the property in question).

Comment: What function are you using to set a parameter? Also, HasProceduralProperty returns a true if it has that property. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, HasProceduralProperty works on ProceduralMaterials. There isn't anything like that for Animators or animator controllers.  And for whatever it's worth, I'm using [SetFloat](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html). Reworded question to emphasise mecanim.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler version, involve GC alloc on Animator.parameters, not cool for repeated call.

```
public static bool HasParameter( string paramName, Animator animator )
{
    foreach( AnimatorControllerParameter param in animator.parameters )
    {
        if( param.name == paramName )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Usage sample
public void SetFloatParamWithCheck( string paramName, float v )
{
    // animator defined elsewhere.
    Animator animator;     

    if( HasParameter( animator, paramName ) )
    {
        animator.SetFloat( paramName , v );
    }
}
```

Extension version, still involve GC alloc every call.

```
public static class AnimatorHelper
{
    public static bool ContainsParam( this Animator _Anim, string _ParamName )
    {
        foreach( AnimatorControllerParameter param in _Anim.parameters )
        {
            if( param.name == _ParamName ) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage sample
public void SetFloatParamWithCheck( string paramName, float v )
{
    // animator defined elsewhere.
    Animator animator;     

    if( animator.ContainsParam( paramName ) )
    {
        animator.SetFloat( paramName , v );
    }
}
```

An over-engineered version. With caching and resolving parameter hash in one go. Premature optimization is evil but you will need it in (some) practice.

```
// Animator parameters query involve GC, cache it
// Animator.GetParameter( index ) might also internally use it, so no better.

Animator m_LastAnimatorCache; // Assume typically working with 1 animator, could extending to collect more cache.
Dictionary<string,int> m_AnimatorParamCache = new Dictionary<string,int>( ); // <key=paramname,value=hash>

private bool TryGetAnimatorParam( Animator animator, string paramName, out int hash )
{
    if( (m_LastAnimatorCache == null || m_LastAnimatorCache != animator) && animator != null ) // Rebuild cache
    {
        m_LastAnimatorCache = animator;
        m_AnimatorParamCache.Clear( );
        foreach( AnimatorControllerParameter param in animator.parameters )
        {
            int paramHash = Animator.StringToHash( param.name ); // could use param.nameHash property but this is clearer
            m_AnimatorParamCache.Add( param.name, paramHash );
        }
    }

    if( m_AnimatorParamCache != null && m_AnimatorParamCache.TryGetValue( paramName, out hash ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        hash = 0;
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage sample
public void SetFloatParamWithCheck( string paramName, float v )
{
    // animator defined elsewhere.
    Animator animator;
    int hash;

    if( TryGetAnimatorParam( animator, paramName, out hash ) )
    {
        animator.SetFloat( hash, v );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon the solutions, this is a simple animator utility class that allows you to check if the animator has a parameter or not, or safely set parameters without any warnings, it is quite fast as it uses a HashSet and Dictionary for caching the parameters and name hashes.

### Download

1. [Get the script from this gist](https://gist.github.com/hasanbayatme/f7f1d9d0f8470b718fda836f6668c215)
2. Import the script into your Unity project

### Examples

Here is a quick usage snippet:

```
float speed = Mathf.Abs(this.rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude);

// Set a parameter safely (it won't log warnings)
animator.SetFloatSafe(this.speedParameter, speed);

// Or manually check if the parameter exists
if (animator.HasParameter(this.speedParameter)) {
  animator.SetFloat(this.speedParameter, speed);
}

// Get a parameter's value safely with a default value
// The "Height" parameter here is missing in the animator and the default height value is returned instead
float defaultHeight = 10f;
float height = animator.GetFloatSafe("Height", defaultHeight);
```

Here is the complete example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Bayat.Games.Animation.Utilities;

public class GameCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

  [Header("Animation")]
  [SerializeField]
  protected Animator animator;
  [SerializeField]
  protected string speedParameter = "Speed";
  
  [Header("Physics")]
  [SerializeField]
  protected new Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

  protected void OnEnable() {
  
    // Allocate caches and resources for this animator (only the first usage allocates the caches, the rest use the same caches for this animator)
    animator.AddAnimatorUsage();
  }
  
  protected void OnDisable() {
  
    // Release caches and unused resources
    animator.RemoveAnimatorUsage();
  }
  
  proteved void LateUpdate() {
  
    float speed = Mathf.Abs(this.rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude);
  
    // Set a parameter safely (it won't log warnings)
    animator.SetFloatSafe(this.speedParameter, speed);
    
    // Or manually check if the parameter exists
    if (animator.HasParameter(this.speedParameter)) {
      animator.SetFloat(this.speedParameter, speed);
    }
    
    // Get a parameter's value safely with a default value
    // The "Height" parameter here is missing in the animator and the default height value is returned instead
    float defaultHeight = 10f;
    float height = animator.GetFloatSafe("Height", defaultHeight);
  }

}
```

### Resources

- [API](https://gist.github.com/hasanbayatme/f7f1d9d0f8470b718fda836f6668c215#api)
- [Features](https://gist.github.com/hasanbayatme/f7f1d9d0f8470b718fda836f6668c215#features)

### License

MIT License.